# Is there a recommended height for text fields on high density mobile screens (retina, etc)?

Tags: forms, mobile, input-fields

I can't seem to find any information about whether text field sizes should be at least a certain height on a high density mobile view like retina or high density android devices. I try to make my text fields and buttons at least 40px tall but that looks short in retina device pixels. Does it even matter how tall the field is as long as they can read the text being input? I want to make then fields at least 60px tall so they can fit bigger font size and so they are easier to activate but I don't want to burden developers right now as we are lacking in resources. Is there a convincing argument for making them taller?

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking iPhones 40px on a non-retina screen is the same height as 40px on a retina screen. The device doubles the height accordingly as needed on retina to make sure it's physically the same size.

Comment: does this apply for safari? it doesn't seem to be doing that...

Comment: @myklee are you talking about a mobile web site? Yes, it does apply, but you also need to tell safari about the viewport settings: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: In other words, if you tell mobile safari that your page is supposed to be the same size as the screen, then yes, it will auto-double. However, if you don't tell safari that, it will do its best to shrink the page to a size it feels best fits the phone.